# Domain entities design

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities

which approach is better and more correct.

```
class Project
int Id
string Name
int CategoryId
```

OR

```
class Project
int Id,
string Name
Category CategoryId
```

Comment: Should your second example read `Category Category` at the end?  Is the `Category` object an instance of a Category class or a value object that represents a category id?

Comment: It should read Category.CategoryID. In example I've posted it is Category class not value object. CategoryID is foreign key in Project table.

Comment: In that case it depends completely on your domain.  If you have `Categories` as part of your `Project` aggregate root, then you'd have to accept all the rules that come with that decision (there's way too many to list here).  The main ones being that you cannot create or modify a `Category` directly or outside of a `Project`.  You would have to modify the `Category` via a method on the `Project` aggregate root.  Although I don't know your domain, I'd imagine you'd want to edit/create `Categories` elsewhere.  If this is the case then example 1 is more correct (for DDD).

Comment: currently I use mapping 1:1 stored procedure and domain object. Is this approach good? In future I would like to use repository pattern with classic ADO.NET.

Comment: Persistence details are usually outside of the realm of DDD.  Ideally when practising DDD you want to design an application/domain-centric model that models your domain.  Because of this, nothing should creep upwards from your chosen persistence layer, into your domain model.  So in other words, persistence can be done any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the domain classes, and not only, moreover, all classes should be declared at singular as they represent a type.

Comment: Logically, one should use entity types in entities which are related (one to one, one to many, etc), if you use JPA, usually Project has one or many Categories, not CategoryIDs.

Comment: No,I used native Ado.Net with DataReader object

Answer (score -1):

Project, rather than Projects, as each instance will represent a single project.

Comment: Sorry, both represent single Project. Focus is on Category attribute.

Comment: It depends somewhat on the implementation (ie are you using Hibernate or another ORM, that has its own style?).  You probably don't want to call the ID "Category" unless some ORM magic makes that compelling. An ID is an ID and not the thing.

Comment: I used native ADO.NET with DataReader object. Until now,we mapped stored procedure with domain object 1:1. And I want to optimize domain model. In database we have Projects table and Category codebook. Project can have only one Category

Comment: If, when you retrieve a project from the database, the category object is fully constructed (and not just an integer), then you may want to call it category. otherwise category id.